# Change input language system wide in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout, dvorak, input-languages

I really like how Mac OS X toggles the input language system wide. Is there a similar feature in Windows 7? It is very annoying when I have to toggle for each application, especially when someone is helping me and they get annoyed with DSK.